# How to crop an image after detecting the Hough line of the horizon using opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, crop, edge-detection, hough-transform

I'm using opencv python for image processing in order to detect the horizon on marine images. My question is: how to crop the rest of the image after applying Canny edge detector and Hough transform? I have to crop the region that is on the right side of the horizon line. Here's my image:
[image: the image]

Comment: This is totally OT: latida, would you consider testing your code with my images? I need to do horizon extraction by my iOS library doesn't implement it yet so I'd like to test.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose you know the maximum X coordinate of the line. Then you just need to access indices of the image's numpy array. That is:

```
cropped = original_image[:,0:max_x]
```

In some cases I had to copy the subimage if I wanted to process it with opencv:

```
cropped = original_image[:,0:max_x].copy()
```

Look up numpy arrays indexing for details...